# Overwrite form mapper field options

Tags: php, forms, symfony

In symfony2 project I am adding a normal form field like this:

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
        ->add('test', 'text', array('empty_data' => 'Default value');

}
```

Now I have another class that extend class above and I need to change empty data value by overwriting `configureFormFields` method (and not removing the field).

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    parent::configureFormFields($formMapper);

    $formMapper->get('test')->??? // (get options or setOption??);
}
```

Anyone know how to set option (overwrite) `empty_data` for the given field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a new input to your form with the same name and type as an existing input, it will override that input. So **in the extended Form Class**:

```
$formMapper->add('test', 'text', array('empty_data' => 'Another Default value'));
```

Comment: I cant do that as its already defined and it may change in the future (parent class), I only want to overwrite one option